# moodle: Automatic plugin updates for developing offline

Tags: moodle

I am developing a plugin for moodle. Every time want to review the results of the things I have changed in the code it is necessary to update all plugins. This means I have to open a notification page and click on update. I waste a lot time by doing this. Furthermore, it requires a internet connection to check for updates online.

Is there a way to update plugins that are under development automatically?

**UPDATE**
Especially changes to the AMD-Files do not become updated. The following steps I have tried:

*First try:*

1. change js-file inside AMD folder
2. [optional] delete minified version of the js-file
3. run grunt (uglify)
4. page reload in firefox or chrome
   => **no changes visible after page reload in firefox**

*Second try:*

1. change js-file inside AMD folder
2. run grunt (uglify)
3. change version number at version.php
4. updated plugin at moodle / administration / site administration / notifications
5. page reload in firefox or chrome
   => **changes are visible**

Cache was disabled in the browser and inside moodle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the config.php in the root folder of moodle and added the following lines:

```
$CFG->cachejs = false;
$CFG->debug = DEBUG_DEVELOPER;
```

Finally, I saw all changes made to Javascript files stored in mod/my-plugin/amd/src directly on the page without running grunt.
It was not enough to set the debugging options under administration / site administration / development / debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to do any form of update if you have just made changes to your code - make the change, save it, refresh the page.

If you have changed any language strings or CSS or created any new autoloading classes, then [Purge the site caches](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Developer_tools#Purge_all_caches) to see the new version.

If debugging is on, you shouldn't need to purge any caches for javascript changes (but you can also set $CFG->jsrev = -1; in config.php, as that sometimes helps).

The only times (during development) when you really need to bump the version number and then visit the notifications page (which doesn't require an internet connection) is if you are adding/removing a capability, changing the database tables in some way or making changes to one of the other files in the 'db/' subfolder (e.g. caches.php, messages.php).

Comment: This does not affect the AMD files. I have updated my question to be more precise.

Comment: Turn debugging on and you will be served the non-minified version of the AMD module and it will be updated as soon as you refresh the page. You only need to run grunt before you deploy to the live server.